# Hide unshown items' height

Tags: html, xslt, html-table

I'm writing custom XSLT attaching to a list in SharePoint 2010.
It gets current page's URL, and filter the retrieved items based on page URL's query string.

For example, carrent page URL is http://sitename.com?ID=5

It will return a list of items but only showing the item ID=5.

However, the div is showing extra height for the rest unshown items. 
Is there a way I can implement the XSLT or HTML to not showing the height of unshown items.

Here's the XSLT: // Updated in 3/26/2018

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
     exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" 
     xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" 
     xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:param name="ListUrlDir"/>
    <xsl:param name="PageUrl"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@ID = substring-after($PageUrl,'=')]"/>     
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                <xsl:sort select="@Group"/>
                <xsl:variable name="newGroup" select="ddwrt:NameChanged(string(@Group),1)"/>
                <tr id="group0">
                    <th class="my-rteElement-PubColoredHeading2" colspan="99"><xsl:value-of select="@Group"/></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="group1">
                    <td class="ms-gb" colspan="99" style="border:none">
                        <a onclick="javascript:ExpGroupBy(this);return false;" href="{$ListUrlDir}/dispform.aspx?id={@ID}">
                        <img border="0" name="expand" alt="expand" src="/_layouts/images/plus.gif" style="float:left;margin:2px 5px 0 0;"/>
                            <span style="float:left;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="" style="display:none;">
                    <td style="width:14px;">
                    </td>
                    <td class="ms-vb">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating rows for each Row, regardless of their ID. Try removing the choose element and adding the selection logic to your variable by using a predicate.

Comment: So I get rid of the choose element, and change the variable to "<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@ID = substring-after($PageUrl,'=')]"/>" It works like a charm, thanks!! (also updated the code, please let me know if there's anything wonky)